# In javascript how can i use regex to validate comma with other characters

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript how can i use regex to validate comma with characters. I'm doing this

```
return /^[a-zA-Z_-]+$/i.test(value);
```

which is working perfect but I want to add comma like this

```
return /^[a-zA-Z_-,]+$/i.test(value);
```

which is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a character class, `-` is a special character (indicating a range between the preceding and the following character) unless it is the first or last character in the class:

```
return /^[a-zA-Z_,-]+$/i.test(value);
```

Comment: cool...with this js error gone but actually I was validating name and have to allow a-z and/or these charecters "-,_" but with this regex its applying "and" condition so comma become mandatory now :(

Comment: @bin2k No. This regex applies `OR` condition for the characters, so comma is NOT mandatory now. Most likely the problem is somewhere else :)